# Executing multiple .SQL Files

Tags: mysql

I have over 200 SQL files which contain misc data that need to be executed into my Mysql Database, I'm wondering if anyone knows a good way to accomplish this task other than executing each file one by one manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In unix, where SOURCE_PATH_ROOT=the path to the root of your sqls, and MYSQL_OPTS=the options to your mysql command:

```
for sqlfile in `find ${SOURCE_PATH_ROOT} -name '*.sql'` ; do
    echo " "
    echo "  Reading `basename ${sqlfile}`"
    mysql ${MYSQL_OPTS} < ${sqlfile}
done
```

Answer (score 2):

simple merge this files into one and execute it